# EF Core + LINQ filter inside list from an array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a filter that can search strings inside an array of strings.

I tried almost 10 methods but the most understandable one is this:

```
var participantArray = query.Participant.Split('|');

// Convert all strings from participantArray to lower case
participantArray = Array.ConvertAll(participantArray, x => x.ToLower());

entities = entities.Where(x.Financeiro.Contrato.Participants.Any(p => participantArray.Contains(p.Person.Name)));
```

For some reason, it doesn't return the expected data. It only returns when only one value is passed.

When the string array has more than one string, it returns null.

The problem also is that `Participants` is a list, when all other fields that is not a list, it works properly.

The expected was to return with all values being passed.

If it's passed like only `{"vono"}` it does return OK.

If `{"topseg sistemas"}` is passed, it does return OK.

But if passed `{"vono", "topseg sistemas"}`, it returns an empty result.

Comment: Your code will not compile. Please correct the final query.

Comment: Nothing obvious comes to mind. Is entries at that point an `IQueryable` that is still pending execution? If so, hook up a profiler to the database to capture the SQL. What database engine is this connected to, and string collation setting? Looking at the generated SQL should reveal what EF is doing as it may be a bug/issue with the DB Provider or need some extra consideration.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of the data in the database, especially for the **'Participants'**, and the exact input you're testing with, so we can better understand the discrepancies you're seeing?

Comment: @FatihFurkanÇambel The `Participants` is a table that has a relation with a table called `Person`, inside `Person` we have the column Name, it's a varchar column.

Also, the input is something like "vono|topseg sistemas". Then I use the .Split('|') method to transform this into a string[].

Comment: Database is PostgreSQL and yes. There are entries before that code. Because that's a filter. For example, before this issue it does a filtering in a column of Clients.

entities = entities.Where(x => x.Financeiro.Contrato.Client.Name.ToLower().Contains(clientsArray)); @StevePy

Comment: The next step would be to use a profiler to capture the queries executed for these scenarios or use something like the log_statement configuration setting on the PostreSQL database to output queries. Are you using the Npgsql EF provider for EF? I would suspect something possibly with string escaping or what the provider is generating (or not) in terms of an `IN` clause etc. There may be a provider-specific discussion/issue raised around using `Array.Contains`.

Comment: How about lowercasing the db value as well, e.g. `Participants.Any(p => participantArray.Contains(p.Person.Name.ToLower()))`? I know it sounds weird, if the original really works with single value, but one never knows what kind of optimizations EFC or provider are doing, and the text comparison rules for `=` and `IN`, so worth trying.

Comment: Would have been nice if you'd mentioned Postgres before.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I implemented your extension method and it filtered right. I tried to do something with expression type but I wasn't doing it right, thank you.
Also, thanks to everyone that helped me in this problem!